# Send message to whatsapp onclick button to particular whastapp number or whatsapp group directly

Tags: android

friends i want my app to save the particular contact number and when any emergency is just on click button , message like "alert" need to be send to particular whats app number or whats app group  how it can be done can u  help me.please give the code directly to send . i do not want the code for sending text and selecting from whats app whom to send. i want my app first let save the any number before and in any emergency just click on button direct sending to particular whastapp number or group.
thanks in advance .
please help me to

Comment: **please give the code** is off-topic. Please show some effort by posting the code you have written so far with specific issue you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the follow

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + "Phone with international format" + "&text=" + "your message";
                    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    if(sendIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null){
                         startActivity(sendIntent);
                    }
```

This will open and intent with specific contact which you have specified.